# Can I tell if a user has subscribed to Office 365 Home with their Microsoft account?

Tags: office365, msdn, azure-active-directory

When authenticating a user using a Microsoft account, can I tell if they've subscribed to Office 365?

I'm particularly interested to know if they have Office 365 Home. Can I call this information?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can read this by looking at [provsionedPlan](http://graph.microsoft.io/GraphDocuments/api-reference/v1.0/resources/provisionedplan.htm) attribute of the user. Check out this sample JSON response:

http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the service would return as Office365Home? What are the possible responses?